# How can I delete pre-installed iPhone shortcuts?

Tags: iphone, ios, shortcuts-app

I opened the Shortcuts app for the first time, and I seem to have 38 pre-installed shortcuts:

[image]

I want to get rid of many of these (e.g., those for Apple Watch, which I will never have, and that for American Airlines, which I rarely fly), but I can't figure out how. The [Apple information on deleting shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/delete-shortcuts-apd096cd65c6/ios) doesn't seem to apply to these shortcuts, because there is no "Edit" to tap on, nor does touching and holding these shortcuts yield a "Delete" option.

How can I cull the herd of shortcuts that have somehow made its way onto my iPhone?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, "Apple Watch" shortcuts are just a filter, like "Share Sheet." Any shortcut can appear here and it can be controlled in the options screen (i) of the shortcut.

Secondly, for the remaining shortcuts surfaced from your apps: I'm not sure why these are counted towards the Shortcut count total, but they're not real shortcuts. They're suggestions surfaced from all installed apps and they always appear below your real shortcuts.

You cannot disable the suggestions except uninstall the app. If you somehow found a way to hide them from this screen, it would be purely cosmetic as they don't yet exist anyways.

Comment: I found that I could delete the shortcuts in the Share Sheet and Apple Watch categories, so those categories are now empty. I can't find a way to get rid of the categories, however. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It will be interesting to see if the shortcut surfaces the next time the responsible app is updated @KnowItAllWannabe

Comment: @bmike the watch/share sheet ones were almost certainly just regular shortcuts so they shouldn't reoccur

Comment: @KnowItAllWannabe If they don't disappear when they're empty, then they can't be hidden. They'r just a part of the shortcuts app